# Stripe Integration not being recognised in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe into my project but seem to be getting an

> NoMethodError in Orders#new undefined method `[ ]' for nil:NilClass"
>   error.

I can't work out how to resolve this. Can anyone help?

This is my Stripe script in new.html.erb

```
<script>
  var stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.credentials.stripe[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe_secret_key] %>")

  var elements = stripe.elements()
  var card = elements.create("card")
  card.mount("#card")
</script>
```

This is what my credentials code looks like

```
stripe:
  development:
    stripe_public_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    stripe_secret_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  test:
    stripe_public_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    stripe_secret_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  production:
    stripe_public_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    stripe_secret_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The error message means either `Rails.application.credentials.stripe` is nil or `Rails.application.credentials.stripe[Rails.env.to_sym]` is nil

Comment: Try them both in the Rails console and ensure they both return values, when you find the one that doesn't you know what to fix

Comment: Sorry newbie here, how do I check it in the Rails console?

Comment: Ok I've done rails c and added both ````Rails.application.credentials.stripe```` and ````Rails.application.credentials.stripe[Rails.env.to_sym]```` and neither of them are coming up with anything.

Comment: That means your secret keys aren't being saved, try following the config steps in https://dev.to/ksushiva/integrate-stripe-in-your-ruby-on-rails-app-3dc4

Comment: I've tried following the link you sent but I'm still getting the same error. I won't allow me to restart the server now either.

Comment: ````Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :public_key => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_public_key],
  :secret_key => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]
````

Comment: This is what I have in my initializers/stripe.rb

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, Rails.env.to_sym, :stripe_secret_key)
```